# How can I activate a style class on click using Mootools or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I would like to create a tab view for my php application using Mootools. I have `n` number of tabs created from php script. My view is as follows.

```
<div>
<ul id="1">
    <li>Popular</li>
    <li>New Addition</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<ul id="2">
    <li>Popular</li>
    <li>New Addition</li>
</ul>
</div>
...
<div>
<ul id="n">
    <li>Popular</li>
    <li>New Addition</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can apply style class `active` according to the clicks on `Populalar` or `New Addition` under each tabs.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var tabs = document.getElements('li');
tabs.addEvent('click', function() {
    tabs.removeClass('active');
    this.addClass('active');
});
```

Try an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/hxQpt/1/).

Comment: +1 for simplicity but `tabs.removeClass('active');` is a little wasteful, esp if it's a long list. `var active; // up the scope chain ... { active.removeClass("active"); this.addClass("active"); active = this; });` would avoid selectors and loops on click. http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/wCkbM/2/

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it in MooTools:

```
var activeElement = null;
$$('div ul li'
   /* you probably want a better selector,
      how about giving a parent element an id? */
  ).each(function(item){
    item.addEvent('click',function(event){
        $(event.target).addClass('active');
        if(activeElement != event.target){
            if(activeElement!=null)
                $(activeElement).removeClass('active');
            activeElement = event.target;
        }
    });
});
```

**Update:** Here's an improved version, thanks [@steweb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528262/steweb), [source](http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/VAX8n/):

```
$$('#containerID li').each(function(item){
    item.addEvent('click',function(event){
        // minor improvement to steweb's code,
        // restrict to .active inside container
        $$('#containerID .active').removeClass('active');
        this.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

It requires the root div to have the id "containerId":

```
<div id="containerId">
<ul id="1">
<!-- etc -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let me try

Comment: Hi @Sean! great answer! +1 obv. By the way, without using event.target and/or using other variables, I tried to improve a little your code: http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/VAX8n/ ;) (the 'containerID' is a suggestion for @Aijth, as you commented, about using an ID)

Comment: @Sean You're welcome ;) ..btw @Anurag version is still better and minified :D

Comment: You don't need the .each, just `$$('#containerID li').addEvent(...`. You can use all element methods to collections of elements as well.

Comment: @arian, yeah, I tend to forget that. I'm originally a Prototype-guy, so I'm not so sure about the small and nifty differences :-)

Comment: I first wanted to say thanks for this answer, as it's helped me a lot today. I've been attempting to make a small modification to it, but with little success I'm afraid. Simply, I'd like to be able to remove all instances of the active class, if you click on the class which is currently active.

Any help with that would be greatly received.

Comment: @Dave go ahead and ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

object.className = 'active';

( Where object is what you want to highlight )